# Putting a chronometer on a button

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been trying to put a chronometer on a button but I couldn't do. When I put chronometer to center of a button , button always covers the chronometer. How can I make it?

This is my Code

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >



    <Chronometer
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/design_default_color_on_primary"
        android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_on_primary"
        android:textSize="80dp"
        android:textStyle=""
        android:layout_centerInParent= "true"
        />


           <Button
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"

            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the button as the first child , and chronmeter as the second one , like this :

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
   
    
     <Button
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                android:gravity="center"
    
                />
   <Chronometer
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/design_default_color_on_primary"
            android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_on_primary"
            android:textSize="80dp"
            android:textStyle=""
            android:layout_centerInParent= "true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit**

Ops I forgot something , its my bad !

Android material introduced the 3d concept which mean if two views are overlapped , then the view with higher Z "the third dimension" will actually be on the top ! So by default Button view has higher value of Z than most of other views like progressBar and TextView and some other views , so what actually you have to do is set override the default by increasing Z of chronometer using attribute elevation and give it a higher elevation , like this :

```
<Chronometer
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/design_default_color_on_primary"
                android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_on_primary"
                android:textSize="80dp"
                android:textStyle=""
                android:layout_centerInParent= "true"
                android:elevation="10dp"/>
```

You can get a better understanding of the so called Z dimension by checking the official [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping)

**Enjoy !**